# MySql select data from two tables without using join but with a single where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySql, can I select data from two separate tables for the same user without using a join and using a single where declaration?

Example:
**table1**

```
userSent | userId
      10 |      1
```

**table2**

```
userNew | userId
     15 |      1
```

**Example sql**

```
(
select userSent from table1
union
select userNew from table2
) where userId = 1;
```

I'm actually trying to get data for the same user, but from different tables. Trying to run two queries at once.

Comment: Why? Why would you NOT use a join, which fits the purpose perfectly here? What are you trying to achieve and why? With a JOIN, you'd have a single WHERE clause so I really don't understand what's going on, unless you're experimenting and learning.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it.

You can do it this way

```
select user from
(
select userSent as user,userId from table1
union all
select userNew,userId from table2
) tab 
where userId = 1;
```

but keep in mind, that you're reading both tables completely first, combine them (probably even in a temporary table when there's much data) and filter this one. **A performance nightmare!** Don't be lazy, fire two queries. Or even better, join those queries.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be useful:

```
SELECT t1.userSent, t2.userId
 FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
   ON t1.userId = t2.userId
WHERE t2.userId = @userId
```

The `WHERE t2.userId = @userId` is optional , in case you'd like to filter the results for a particular user.

You should not seek to avoid table joins. The database engine has ways to best optimize join queries, especially if you also have the appropriate foreign keys. Non-join queries might be internally rewritten as joins, but that depends on the way the database engine works, and you must definitely **not rely** on that. (I think MySQL engine does not have these rewrite capabilities)

Comment: +1 You are right, I deleted my answer. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @Parado, I appreciate this, thanks. Still I think you could have rewritten your answer instead of deleting it, I did not intend with my comments to lead to such a radical action.

Comment: It is your idea and you should put in as an answer, my idea was wrong so id shouldn't exist. I know you've done everything with good intentions.